# Pentaho 9.1 CE Server - MySQL Erro TimeStamp

Tags: ubuntu, pentaho

I have a Pentaho 9.1 CE Server running on my Ubuntu 18.04, when I'm trying to create my data_source connecting to MySQL database, I can connect, but when I click on "Finish" on the Data Source Wizard, I get this error:

> Error determining value metadata from SQL resultset metadata.

This only happens when the table has a column on the format : timestamp , date.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was because the version of MySQLConnector-Jar , the version 5.49 fixed .